# correcting misplaced text in a large text file

Tags: python, localization, notepad++

i am working on a machined translation of a large text file which i wanted to automate, the file looks like this,

```
<TEXT>
    <Unknown1>-65535</Unknown1>
    <autoId>1</autoId>
    <autoId2>0</autoId2>
    <alias>Name2.Boast_Duel_Season01_sudden_death_1vs1</alias>
    <replacement>Уникальная массовая дуэль: Битва один на один до полного уничтожения в один раунд</replacement>
  </TEXT>
  <TEXT>
    <Unknown1>-65535</Unknown1>
    <autoId>2</autoId>
    <autoId2>0</autoId2>
    <alias>Name2.Boast_Duel_Season01_sudden_death_3vs3</alias>
    <replacement>Уникальная массовая дуэль: Битва трое на трое до полного уничтожения в один раунд</replacement>
  </TEXT>
  <TEXT>
    <Unknown1>-65535</Unknown1>
    <autoId>3</autoId>
    <autoId2>0</autoId2>
    <alias>Name2.Boast_MuSinTower_step01</alias>
    <replacement>Первое воплощение Бога Войны: Боль</replacement>
```

the guys here helped me build a script, and after a little modification i've done, i managed to extract the text i need translated, using this script,

```
import re

def loadfile(filename):
    '''
    Returns a string containing all data from file
    '''
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    infile_string = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    return infile_string


def main():
    #load the files into strings
    original = loadfile("original.xml")


    #grab all of the "TEXT" blocks from the original file
    original_regex = re.compile("(<original>.*?</original>)", re.DOTALL)
    original_list = original_regex.findall(original)


    #a string to write out to the new file
    outfile_string = ""
    for i in range(len(original_list)): #loop through all of the original text blocks
        #build a new string with the replacement text only
        build_string = ""
        build_string += original_list[i]
        build_string += "\n" + " "*4
        outfile_string+=build_string


    #write the outfile string out to a file
    outfile = open("replacement.xml", 'w')
    outfile.write(outfile_string)
    outfile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

now i have the file with only the text needed to be translated (near 300k lines of text),

```
 <replacement>Золотой великан</replacement>
    <replacement>Серкет</replacement>
    <replacement>Предводитель Хакан</replacement>
    <replacement>Посвященный У Кахи</replacement>
    <replacement>Лидер банды Чугуна Хви Бичжок</replacement>
    <replacement>Предводитель Сок Самчжа</replacement>
    <replacement>Глава охранников гробницы</replacement>
    <replacement>Древняя гробница</replacement>
    <replacement>Василиск с крыльями вихря</replacement>
```

the problem is that after running it with google translate,the formatting gets pretty messed up, the translated products sometime have a single word before the  header and that's not acceptable,

```
<replacement> Golden Giant </ replacement>
    <replacement> Serket </ replacement>
    Hakan <replacement> Leader </ replacement>
    Dedicated <replacement> Kakha </ replacement>
    The gang's leader <replacement> Cast Iron Hwee Bichzhok </ replacement>
    <replacement> Leader Samji Juice </ replacement>
    <replacement> Chapter guards tomb </ replacement>
    <replacement> Ancient tomb </ replacement>
    <replacement> Basilisk with wings swirl </ replacement>
```

i can work out the other formatting problems, but i really can't figure out this one, any suggestion or modification on the original script is welcomed, thanks.

EDIT: i think the replace command in "notepad++" maybe of help, i just don't know how exactly.
added notepad++ to the tags.

**EDIT 2**: i have found a solution that's very simple but requires a tad bit more modification, i just opened the file, searched for all the `<replacement>` strings, and deleted them! now all the text is concentrated correctly and i just have to add the string `<replacement>` to the start of each line the in the document..
now, how can i do that?

Comment: Since it looks like an `XML` file, why don't use an [`XSLT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) transformation?

Comment: i have little to no knowledge about XSLT, and i just started to look into python a few days ago..so that's probably why.

Comment: then show us some more examples with line breaks and the resulting translations

Comment: well, i have the file already uploading in it's current format (and it's quite large,really..there is a website that i found that ignores google docs file size limits) removing the line break or tags means i should start to re-upload it, and it's already been too long since i started.
if all else fails, i think i will try that, but in the meantime, i am looking for a way to offset each <replacement> tag to the beginning of the line it's in. currently googling for solutions outside the range of only python, too

Comment: after a bit of digging, i think there is a function in notepad++ that does that with the replace command? i still don't quite get it,though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are diving into python already, there's good news: you can get your XML file translated already with python. Take a look at python's [Goslate](http://pythonhosted.org//goslate/) module, which is an interface for Google's Translate engine.

First, install goslate using `pip install goslate` or `easy_install goslate`, as it is not included in most python distributions.

Next, you can ask translate engine to translate your strings into desired language, and write translated string in output file. Simply use code like:

```
import goslate
gs = goslate.Goslate()

# set your text_to_be_translated here in reading loop
text_translated = gs.translate(text_to_be_translated, target_language,source_language)
```

and you have translated `text_to_be_translated` with no additional operations needed.

Comment: that would be pretty awesome indeed!

Comment: that would be pretty awesome indeed! i have tried the code you provided but i get the error: "non-ascII charcters 'xd0' in file but no encoding declared"
since i am a total noob at this as it shows, i went and looked up the goslate page, but i don't know what's wrong..

Comment: that error says that you are using non-ascii characters in your script, but script doesn't have encoding declared. Add to the top of your script line `# coding=<encoding name>` like described in PEP 0263 (http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) (I don't know what codepage you are using).

Comment: well, it's detecting the <replacement> tag as an invalid syntax! so i guess we are back at square one again.
thanks for the reply and it would have been awesome, but i guess i still have to look for a way to offset that tag to the start of the line like i initially intended..

Comment: @user3658890 - I won't help with it without knowing your code. Describe it in your question if you want an answer.

Comment: i really don't know what i am doing, my knowedge of python is just too low for me to pull this off, i used the code provided in this page:
https://github.com/rishabhsixfeet/TRanslate/blob/master/googletranslate.py
and i just replaced the "enter the string to be translated" with my huge amount of text, and then changed the destination language to "en", renamed the file to (replacement) and ran it!
yup, it's pretty obvious that i don't know what i am doing here!